# terraform resource i/p parameters possible values

Tags: terraform

I am new to terraform and want to know the possible values of the options we use in commands, ex we have aws_ami data source and we have virtualization type, name , owner etc in it . Where do I get the various possible values of these and if I dont put anything then what are default values of these. As a general question how do we get the values of various i/p parameters in resources

Comment: Have you read the docs? The providers all have documentation for the data sources and resources, explaining required parameters and what things default to. Is there something specific you don't understand about them?

Comment: Yes I read the docs , for ex https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html, In this case there are lot of arguments , but where do i get the values of some of these arguments  like virtualization type , is there some reference where all its values and default values given ?

Comment: There's nothing particularly terraform about those properties , they are all attributes for AWS, have a look at those objects in the UI and cli it should be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @james Woolfenden , You are correct I have to look into UI only for all these values.I thought maybe there is some easier way to find all these values directly from terraform

One way to get the required values for any resource directly from terraform is include the resource with empty braces in the tf file and then execute it , terraform will give an error with the required values for it.